# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Tags: angular

Please i am new to Angular and i am following a tutorial by Felipe Coury.
in a chapter of the book(writing your first angular 2 web application), He uses ".value" to display the title and the link in which we are to input. for him it worked well but on my system it keeps showing "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". i don't know if it is because i upgraded my angular cli to 4.5.0.
please if you have a solution kindly help me.

This are my codes

```
    app.component.ts

    import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import { Article } from 'app/article/article.model';

    @Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
    addArticle(title: HTMLInputElement, link: HTMLInputElement): boolean {
    console.log(`Adding article title: ${title.value} and link: 
    ${link.value}`);

    this.articles.push(new Article (title.value, link.value, 0));
    title.value='';
    link.value='';
    return false;
    }
    articles:Article[];

    constructor() {
    this.articles = [
    new Article ('Angular 2', 'http://www.angular.io', 3),
    new Article ('Fullstack', 'http://www.fullstack.io', 10),
    new Article ('Anguar Home page', 'http://www.angular.io', 4)
    ]
    }
    }
```

this is the app.component.html

```
    app.component.html
    <form class="ui large form segment">
    <h3 class="ui header">Add a Link</h3>

    <div class="field">
    <label for="title">Title:</label>
    <input name="title"  #newtitle>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
    <label for="link">Link:</label>
    <input  name="link"  #newlimk>
    </div>

    <button (click)="addArticle(newtitle, newlink)"
     class="ui positive right floated button">
    Submit link
    </button>
    </form>
    <div class="ui grid posts">
    <app-article
    *ngFor="let foobar of articles"
    [article]="foobar">
    </app-article>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
 <input name="link" #newlink>
```

So.. `newlink` instead of `newlimk`